# How to POST to salesforce custom object?

Tags: salesforce, webrequest

I'm trying to POST information to a salesforce custom object, I can do it using postman. I can do a GET call already and get the information back, I have tried reading the salesforce REST API, google etc. and I just cant figure it out and I get a 400 - Bad request error.

Here's  my code:

```
 Dim jsonFields as string="{"Related_Claim__c", "a060U0000048UZRQA2"},{"Name", "TEST-08182020"}})
    Dim req As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://na123.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/Letters__c")
    req.ContentType = "application/json"
    req.Method = "POST"
    req.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer 00D0U0000009rxm!AQsAQP.08BW_eXhCyx_EcrLmT.h8Ckt4PfmhZSSj7Gro8rV3U3e0.rsdJ1nX6TVMmcePkSunMdmnLf0Zjfl2EglHp392mnsk")
    Dim JsonSerialized As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonFields)
    Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerialized )
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length
    Dim os As System.IO.Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    os.Close()
    Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the final endpoint you're POSTing to? Should be based on something you've read back from login call, not the generic "test.salesforce.com / login.saleslforce.com". What's the raw text output of that dictionary & stream manipulation, simple `{"Related_Claim__c", "a060U0000048UZRQA2", "Name", "TEST-08182020"}`?

Comment: I updated my post with the endpoint, and the token to make it more understandable. I'm just trying to insert a new record into a salesforce custom object using HttpWebRequest and JSon.

Comment: `jsonfields` is wrong. Too many curly braces, it has to be 1 object with 2 fields. This is 2 free floating objects, not even wrapped in an array? I don't even understand the VB syntax, this compiles?  Doest complain about unmatched quotes and curly braces?  If it's raw string now serialising it extra sounds wrong, it'll escape all quotes unnecessarily, right? Was "na123..." returned in the login call's response? Bit weird, everybody tends to have mydomain these days.

Comment: The jsonFields string was just an example of what I'm trying to post. here's how the JSon looks like: {
"Related_Claim__c":"a060U0000048oGWQAY",
"Name":"TEST-08182020",
"Type__c":"CRC",
"Template_ID__c":"APL302"
}

Comment: But I already figured out how to post it and it works, I tried with a different object and it does work. I think there's something else going on with the original object, some flow trigger. The thing is that on postman I get an specific error as the response, but with the code I just get a 400 Bad call error. Thanks for your help @eyescream.

Comment: you'd see flow/trigger error in the response's body (do you check just the status code or payload too?). or you can enable debug logging on your integration user in SF -> Setup -> Debug Logs. If you haven't made any obvious typos it's really hard to say, if it works in postman, if it logs in to SF ok it's not some problems with proxies or something.